# c++: gcc bug when combining auto and r-value in methods?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, clang++

The following code uses return type deduction (auto) and different methods for L-value and R-value objects. It seems when combining the two, gcc 4.9.2 has problems with overload resolution: "call of overloaded 'f()' is ambiguous".
Is this a bug or just another strange C++ corner case? Clang accepts it as expected.

```
struct T {
  auto f() & {
    return int{0};
  }
  auto f() && {
    return string{""};
  }
};

void test_it() {
  //Calling with L-value object. Fails with "call of overloaded 'f()' is ambiguous").
  T t;
  int s = t.f();

  //Calling with R-value object. Fails with "call of overloaded 'f()' is ambiguous").
  string i = T{}.f();
}
```

The example can be studied using online compilers here:
gcc 4.9.2: http://goo.gl/IE19y8
clang 3.5.1: http://goo.gl/FRbD8Z

Comment: Works fine in Clang 3.7; confirmed in GCC 4.9.2. File a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a known bug:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60943